# VBA Macro - remove tabs from selected table

Tags: vba, tabs, ms-word

I have a small macro designed to clear the selected table of any tab characters.

It works exactly as expected for me; however, the user who requested it is reporting that it clears her entire document of tabs (realistically, not bad because we don't recommend the use of tabs in MSWord anyway..)

I was hoping that a more experienced macro maker could examine the small macro to make sure it should do what it was designed to do (and what I verified it does)

```
Sub RemoveTabs()
Selection.Tables(this).Select
With Selection
    .Find.Text = Chr(9)
    .Find.Replacement.Text = ""
    .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Oh, "This" is a global constant equaling 1. I don't like seeing numbers in my code where it can be avoided, probably should make a library of chr codes now that I think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code removes the space completely because

`""` is not equal to `" "` and `chr(32)`

Just to be safe, change your code to this

```
Sub RemoveTabs()
    Selection.Tables(this).Select
    With Selection
        .Find.Text = Chr(9)
        .Find.Replacement.Text = Chr(32)
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

and youre good to go!

---

I reproduced the behavior by Inserting a Table and entering two words separated by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>

[image]

Then ran your original code and got:

[image]

So I inserted the tabs again and after changing

```
.Find.Replacement.Text = ""
```

to

```
.Find.Replacement.Text = Chr(32)
```

or

```
.Find.Replacement.Text = " "
```

it worked fine !

[image]

Comment: This means it works exactly as I need it to. We don't have problems with tabs between words and replacing tabs with spaces would actually cause more issues requiring me to implement the trim function as well; however, using that method with track changes enabled would cause some serious issues (we have to keep track changes on at all times per company policy). Thank you for verifying it though, I appreciate it :)

Comment: @user2733199, if you don't like numbers, then replacements you could do is change `Chr(9)` to `vbTab` or `Chr(vbKeyTab)`, and `32` can be change to `vbKeySpace`

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following line after "With Selection"

> .Find.Wrap = wdFindStop

When using Find/Replace, it's often a good idea to explicitly set/clear a lot of the Find options. e.g. you could Macro Record a Find/Replace option and adapt the code that Word generates.